# How to display a query set in the django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I wish to over ride the `django admin` to display a `list` of recently added events in the admin page. I read about `queryset` in the docs but it is probably for returning a queryset that can be `changed by the admin`. I just want it to display it at the right of the page or bottom of the page. Position is not a big issue at the moment. I have a `datetime` field on which I will do the query. What is a possible way for this?

Comment: What is wrof if you do a queryset in your modeladmin?

Comment: I didnt fully understand it. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To override the queryset you can do this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(date__year="2013")     
        else:
            return qs


class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

admin.site.register(MyModel, ModelAdmin)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you tell me about the request?

Comment: According to the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) `Django uses request and response objects to pass state through the system.

When a page is requested, Django creates an HttpRequest object that contains metadata about the request. Then Django loads the appropriate view, passing the HttpRequest as the first argument to the view function. Each view is responsible for returning an HttpResponse object.`

Comment: I think it is supposed to be `class MyModelAdmin()`

Comment: Im trying it out. Once I get it done I will definitely approve it. :)

Comment: I get this error :  `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: The error is that you wrote `request` instead of `self` 
Change this `qs = super(IncidentAdmin, request).queryset(request)` to this
`qs = super(IncidentAdmin, self).queryset(request)`

Comment: This code isnt breaking anything. But it isnt displaying any results.

Comment: I printed it out in the terminal. Gives me the results. But not in my django admin.

Comment: Okay. now tell me something. this query is supposed to return results in the model admin page or the page where I add model tuples?

Comment: In this page http://www.theotherblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/django_admin.jpg

Comment: Okay. Its working. I was expecting it in the add_model page. :(

Comment: What if I wish to display both the queryset and all the tuples in separate blocks? Is it possible?

Comment: Lool at the ModelAdmin methods (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods)